# custom authentication in jupyterhub

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid-connect, jupyterhub

I would like to implement edu-id authentication in jupyterhub. edu-id supports OpenIDConnect (https://help.switch.ch/eduid/docs/services/openid-connect/).

Does anyone have any idea how I can implement it in jupyterhub oauth?
This thread might be also helpful https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator/issues/672#issuecomment-1686081823

They also have implemented oauth using github, google, etc., here https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator

here is a code snippet from an old presentation [image]